# Работа с WinRar в C#

Tags: c#, .net, архивация, winrar

Подскажите, как можно работать с WinRar в C#?

Я находил вариант с использованием консольного режима, но может быть есть какая-нибудь удобная библиотека ?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "работать с WinRar"? Создавать и распаковывать rar архивы?

Comment: Да, именно это.

Answer (score 5):

Поиск `rar` на nuget.org выдал библиотеку [SharpCompress](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/). Согласно документации, поддерживает распаковку rar-архивов (но не упаковку).

Подключив пакет, я скомпилировал следующий код:

```
using SharpCompress.Reader;

// ...

using (var archive = File.OpenRead(@"D:\PathSegments.rar"))
using (var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(archive))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Archive type: " + reader.ArchiveType);
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
        if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
            Console.WriteLine(
                "File: {0} size {1}/{2}",
                reader.Entry.Key, reader.Entry.CompressedSize, reader.Entry.Size));
    }
}
```

который выдал:

> Archive type: Rar
>   File: App.config size 135/187
>   File: App.xaml.cs size 159/345
>   File: AspectRatioDecorator.cs size 945/6224
>   File: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs size 764/2288
>   File: PartialSegmentControl.xaml size 192/1079
>   ...

Ещё примеры [здесь](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/wiki/API-Examples).

Answer (score 1):

Формат RAR проприетарный. Алгоритмы распаковки и исходники UnRAR защищены авторскими правами, но доступны для бесплатного использования. Взять можно на **[RarLab](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm)**. Упаковку в RAR можно сделать только родным архиватором. А про распаковку уже ответил VladD.

Answer (score 0):

Сколько не искал, ничего удобного для WinRAR не находил. Зато есть для [7-zip](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/), может подойдет.